# Error porting ASN1C source files from PC to STM32 (ARM)

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, asn.1

I am trying to port the code I generated using ASN1C to encode a structure using UPER.

First, I wanted to test the code in my computer so I generated a CodeBlocks project, included those files and verified that the encoding was correct using the console.

Now I have included the same files in my Keil uVision project for an STM32L476 target. After solving some minor issues involving type definitions I am able to compile. But I get the following errors in the linking part:

> ```
> Build started: Project: WMB-IOT_APP_MOD
> Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 7 (build 960)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARM_Compiler_5.06u7\Bin'
> Build target '08647APP_MOD_L_V4'
> linking...
> .\OUT__APP_LM_V4\08647_APP_V200.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol __stdout multiply defined (by stdio_streams.o and utils_stm32.o).
> .\OUT__APP_LM_V4\08647_APP_V200.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol __stdin multiply defined (by stdio_streams.o and utils_stm32.o).**
> Not enough information to list image symbols.
> Not enough information to list load addresses in the image map.
> Finished: 2 information, 0 warning and 2 error messages.
> ".\OUT__APP_LM_V4\08647_APP_V200.axf" - 2 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
> Target not created.
> Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:03
> ```

As you can see it seems there is a multiple definition of the input and output streams. The thing is that I cannot find `__stdin` or `__stdout` mentioned in any of the files that ASN1C creates. In my understanding there should not be any problem related to it since the code is supposed to be portable. I even deleted the jer and xer encoders, which made use of some stdio functions that I do not need. I feel like I am missing on some advanced embedded C knowledge.

I tried looking at any possible definition of `__stdin` or `__stdout` but I cannot find. I defined `ASN_EMIT_DEBUG` as `0` and disabled support for XER and JER.

Comment: Embedded system compilers need not implement `stdio.h`, it's optional for so-called freestanding systems. In case Keil does offer it, you might need to set some particular project option. What are those object files anyway, do you have files called `stdio_streams.c` or `utils_stm32.c` or are these from library code added by Keil?

Comment: The symbols `__stdin` and `__stdout` are not defined by C.  They are of a form that is explicitly reserved for use by your C implementation.  I am not surprised that you don't find them in your source files: ASN1C would be wrong to generate or rely on those symbols.

Comment: Btw make sure you perform a clean build because many compilers use the .o extension for object files but they are not compatible for sure in this case. Just delete anything in your local or \bin folder named *.o.

Comment: The `__stdin` and `__stdout` symbols are probably entering your translation units via inclusion of one or more system headers.  It's unclear why or how that would be erroneous, but as @Lundin observes, fewer requirements are placed on C implementations targeting freestanding environments (roughly speaking: those running on bare metal, without benefit of an operating system to support them), and providing `stdio.h` or any of the functions that are declared there in a hosted environment are not among them.

Comment: Update: I started a new project with STM32CubeIDE and the code compiles and, more importantly, works correctly. I only had to do the following adaptations to the code: set ASN_EMIT_DEBUG as 0 and replace the includes from the ASN1C generated files from <> to "". These two steps I also followed in Keil uVision without success.

Comment: The compiler may add the __ to some symbols.  Look for undecorated `stdin` / `stdout`.  There should be just one of each.  You have two modules that define them. stdio_streams.o and utils_stm32.o.  one is clearly toolchain/platform specific, and probably the one you want, the other you can probably omit.  They are likely generated from source utils_stm32.c (or .s) and stdio_streams.c/.s.

Comment: Noting also that the Keil toolchain's stdio implementation differs significantly from Cube which uses GCC/Newlib.  Some sources are from devpacks which by default are stored in your Windows user profile not the project or Keil installation (the location is shown and can be changed on installation).  It also appears in the tools.ini file in the Keil installation I think.